# How to know the vertical position of the command prompt?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

By command prompt, I mean that for instance: `[root@hostname][~]#`

I need to display a line 2 lines below the command promt

I can set the *absolute* position with

`tput cup <x> 0`

Kwowing the value of the vertical position of the command prompt would solve my problem

**How can I know the vertial position of the command prompt in my terminal?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to get the cursor position in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575037/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-bash) on Stack Overflow. Essentially,

```
echo -en '\e[6n'
read -sdR CURSORPOS
CURSORPOS="${CURSORPOS#*[}"
```

`$CURSORPOS` will be <line>`;`<column>. Works for Gnome Terminal, XTerm, Linux console.